# NGXS - accessing child state from parent state

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I have parent-child states:

```
@State({
     name: 'parent',
     default: { parentProp : 'foo' },
     children: [
        ChildState,
     ]
}) class ParentState {}
```

and

```
@State({
     name: 'child',
     default: { childProp: 'bar' },
}) class ChildState {}
```

then in an action in the parent state, I'd like to get the state from the child.
Is there a way how can I do it in an action handler, at this point I don't see how to do it, because action handler has the only `StateContext` and action payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I could do something like

```
const child = <ChildStateModel>this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.child);
```

or just use

```
@Action(context: StateContext<ChildStateModel>, action: any)
```

if need to access only to the child

Comment: hi, can u provide your classes ? i need to implement state and substate, and i'm new using ngxs

Comment: Take a look how you could get access to any state here https://github.com/fisenkodv/itinerary/blob/53f222c2c235e6d4047aea06e30a209a8bcf68c0/src/app/modules/places/components/search-panel/search-panel.component.ts#L82 or even better example is here https://github.com/fisenkodv/itinerary/blob/53f222c2c235e6d4047aea06e30a209a8bcf68c0/src/app/modules/places/state/places.state.ts#L57

Comment: `@Action(context: StateContext<ChildStateModel>, action: any)` does not work. `@Action` decorator does not have this overrides. I think you mean something like `@Action(FooAction) fooAction(context: StateContext<ChildStateModel>, action: FooAction)` - which also doesn't work: context type is not `ChildStateModel` but something like `{parentProp: string; child: ChildStateModel}` ('child' is the name of substate)

Answer (score 0):

You can add optional property to your model interface / type with name of substate.
This way, you doesnt have to fill `default:` in your `@State` decorator and still have access to your substate from parent

This is how I did it:

```
/*
please note that this is only example ;)
Substate with only one property probably isnt what you need...

Also please note that I am not using interfaces but types 
(its not called InterfaceScript, is it? ;) ) - should be the same with interfaces 
*/

// name of sub-state to keep typing in our state models / contexts / etc.
export const selecteBookStateName = 'selectedBook'; 
export type Book = { title: string };

export type LibraryStateModel = { 
  books: Book[];
  loading: boolean;
  // this is the line with magic
  // `[variable]: type` means "use value of variable as property name"
  // `foo?: type` means "property foo is optional"
  // Combined, we use this as "optional property named value of selecteBookStateName"
  [selecteBookStateName]?: SelectedBookStateModel;
};
export type SelectedBookStateModel = { model: Book | null; };


// helper state operator so we dont have to care about 
// actual value of `selecteBookStateName` and still keep code type safe
export function patchSelectedBookSubState(
  selectedRepository: Partial<SelectedBookStateModel>
): StateOperator<LibraryStateModel> {
  return patch({
    [selecteBookStateName]: patch<SelectedBookStateModel>(selectedRepository),
  });
}

@State<LibraryStateModel>({
  name: 'library',
  defaults: {
    books: [],
    loading: false,
    // note that I did not specify "selectedBook" here - its optional, I dont have to.
  },
  children: [SelectedBookState],
})
@Injectable()
export class LibraryState {

@Action(SelectBook)
selectBook(ctx: StateContext<LibraryStateModel>, action: SelectBook)
  const state = ctx.getState();

  // we should expect substate to be undefined
  // it should never be, but we lost this info when we make substate optional in our library type.
  // I didnt solve this (And I dont really care)
  const current: SelectedBookState | undefined = state.selectedBook?.model;
  // another way to access the substate.
  const current2: SelectedBookState | undefined = state[selecteBookStateName]?.model;

  // NGXS doc told you to never use setState or you will erase the context of substate.
  // this is not the case, we returned `patch()` from our helper state operator.
  ctx.setState(patchSelectedBookSubState(action.payload));
}


@State<SelectedBookStateModel>({
  // constant from before.
  name: selecteBookStateName, 
  defaults: {
    model: null
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class SelectedBookState {
  @Action(BorrowBookOrSomething)
  borrowBook(ctx: StateContext<SelectedBookStateModel>)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```